# How to prove that this sequence is decreacing?

Tags: limits

I have to examine limit of following sequence:

$$a_n = \sqrt[n]{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(k^{999} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)}}$$

We know that for $a>0$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a} = 1$ and $a_n > 0$ and if we prove that $a_n$ is decreasing we can use the squeeze theorem to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$.

I checked in wolframalpha that $a_n$ is decreasing but I don't know how to prove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No need to prove that it is decreasing.
Lower bound:
$$
a_n>1.
$$
Upper bound:
$$
a_n<\Bigl(n\cdot n^{999}\Bigr)^{1/n}=n^{1000/n}.
$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$.

Comment: But how to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1000/n}=1$ using equation $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1$?

Comment: Now I see $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1000/n}=1 = \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n} \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n} ... \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}$